# Store currently viewed Outlook email body into string

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I am creating a VSTO add-in to capture the user's currently selected email (the one they are reading) and send that selected text as a string to a python script for processing.

I am not sure how to take the currently viewed email's body and store it into a single string.  I have run across solutions using `mailItem.Body` to add text into a newly created email, I cannot find a way to get the text within the body from the email being viewed in the users inbox.

I was thinking something like this might work:

```
public void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
    Inspector.CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
    string test = mailItem.Body; //store email body as string
    MessageBox.Show(test); //verify the string was properly stored
 }
```

However, I believe the code above would only work if a user wanted the text from an email currently being written? What can I use to get the text from an email's body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code for getting selected email body text

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
   private Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange += ExplorerSelectionChange;
    }
    private void ExplorerSelectionChange()
    {
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            Object selItem = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selItem as Outlook.MailItem);
                string bodyText= mailItem.Body; //GET PlainTExt
                 string bodyHTML=mailItem.HTMLBody; //Get HTMLFormat
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Quick question.  What is the significance of "crminfoURL" in '!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crminfoURL)' , I understand that its a string parameter, but where is it coming from?

Comment: It was mistakenly added that. Please check my update answer. If you need further help. Let me know. I have already developed more than 100 of commercial Outlook Add-In

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thank you for the clarification.